# Connecting to Subversion hosted on a Windows XP machine?

Tags: svn, windows-xp, tortoisesvn

I have successfully installed SVN on a Windows XP machine and can connect to it locally.  But I do not know how to connect to it via another machine on the network.

The project is at

> C:\svn\project

And I connect to it via Tortoise locally and want to remotely via another machine - how do I do it?  Thank you.

Comment: what have you installed on your windows xp machine? tortoisesvn client? that isn't a subversion server in the sense i think you're looking for

Comment: Did you install a server for svn: or http: access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to connect from an other machine you have to install svnserve as a service on the Windows machine or use Apache for a Setup. I would suggest to use http://www.visualsvn.com and take a look for VisualSVN Server which you can use.